# Pythonic grid search

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I'm trying to do a grid search to find the optimal number of layers and neurons for my neural network. I do it like the code below but I want to do it in a pythonic way. Could you please help me out with how to write it more elegantly?

For the number of layers I do:

```
config_list = [[ne, 100, 2], [ne, 100, 100, 2], [ne, 100, 100, 100, 2], [ne, 100, 100, 100, 100, 2], 
          [ne, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 2], [ne, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 2], 
          [ne, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 2], [ne, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 2]] 
 
for config in config_list:
        print("Number of hidden layers:", len(config)-2)
        print("--------------------------------------------------------")
        model = NeuralNet(config, kernel_size).to(device)
```

And I do a second grid search for the number of neurons like this:

```
config_list = [[ne, 20, 20, 20, 2], [ne, 30, 30, 30, 2], [ne, 50, 50, 50, 2], [ne, 80, 80, 80, 2], [ne, 100, 100, 100, 2]] 


for config in config_list: 
        model = NeuralNet(config, kernel_size).to(device)
        print('number of neurons', config)
```

Comment: there is a great post made by Jason Brownlee that explains everything regarding doing a grid search for neural networks in Python. It can be found at https://machinelearningmastery.com/hyperparameter-optimization-with-random-search-and-grid-search/ The great thing about grid searches is that you can examine multiple hyperparameters at once, as this allows for the best combination of hyperparameters to be found. It might be best for you to do just the one grid search for both neurons and number of layers.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this post. Actually, it uses the grid search of scikit-learn which only works directly with TensorFlow models. Mine is written in PyTorch. So I can't use this option.
And about combining the neurons and layers I totally agree with you but first I don't know how to do it and then I don't know how to do it in a pythonic way without 4 or 5 for loops.